# wp_update_user very slow

Tags: user-roles, rest-api, wp-api

I am changing a user role with a custom endpoint. If the ID is incorrect, it fails right away and I get my error message. If it is successful however, the role is updated in the backend right away but I don't get the 200 response quickly. It just seems to hang forever and eventually I get the response.I tried the code without actually updating the user ie: leaving out the wp_update_user bit and it is way faster.

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

      register_rest_route( 'userapi/v1', 'change-role', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'change_user_role',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
      ) );
    } );
    
    function change_user_role() {
       $userId = filter_var($_POST['userId'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
       $new_role = 'vip';
       $result = wp_update_user(array('ID'=>$userId, 'role'=>$new_role));
        
        if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'usr_error', $result, array( 'status' => 500 ) );
        } else {
           return new WP_REST_Response( array( 'message' => 'Update successful' ), 200 );
        }
    }
```

Comment: note that with permission callback set to always return true, anybody can change any users role to `vip`, even logged out users,

Comment: Thanks Tom. I am putting another mechanism in place where a long code is going to have to be inputted by the user as opposed to them having to be authenticated. In the meantime I am just trying to figure out why it is so very slow to update the user.

Comment: can you be more specific? Slowness is a very vague and ambiguous thing, and we don't know what additional code is running via actions/filters when `wp_update_user` is called. it could be that you have millions of users, that it isn't slow at all but your frontend runs lots of super expensive database queries that slow it down (e.g. NOT IN/meta_query/meta_key/orderby rand/etc), or that there are plugins doing expensive things when users are updated,  or lots of other things, it's impossible to tell

Comment: Remember you question needs to be specific enough that someone can write an answer using concrete facts for all people with this question, and that can be marked as not just the best response, but the official answer. This isn't a discussion forum so an open ended investigation doesn't fit this sites format, I'd suggest gathering more data, particularly profiling data, as well as testing the endpoint with the rest of the sites theme/plugins disabled and re-enabled slowly to identify influencing code